# Is this possible to convert one array to another given array?

Tags: number-theory, puzzle, permutations

you are given two arrays having n elements ,

like for n=4,suppose

array1={1,2,3,4}

array2={2,1,4,5}

convert array 1 to array2  performing  operation minimum number of time . Also state if transformation is not possible.***I want a general condition for any two given arrays***.

OPERATION- chose a ith element and decrement it by one and increment a all other elements by 1.

Comment: Have you even tried applying that transformation to the given array?

Comment: no i have not tried for above arrays... arrays having solution are-{0,3,4} and{1,4,2}.

Comment: first you should detect when it will have solution then optimize that.

Comment: So you felt that instead of trying to solve it yourself, it was easier to just ask it here and hope someone would do it for you? The least you could do was take a quick look and see what applying the operation once would do, with varying choices of element.

Comment: no i tried thinking about many aspects like equating single element then the sum ofthe differences between corresponding elements of both arrays shuld be even..but have no proof for correctness and unable to generalize it.

Comment: Are you trying to find a general condition that works for any array, or trying to solve the problem for the given arrays, or for some specific set of arrays?

Comment: not particularly for these arrays .i want a general condition for any two arrays.

Comment: Why would this not be possible?

Comment: simple you can not convert {2} to {3} with that operation. can you?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  what happens to the sum of the elements under your operation?  What does that tell you about whether this is possible?

Comment: that will be always n-2 greater than the previous sum .. but m not what to predict from this?please explain?

Comment: @Ross what about in minimum attempts?

Comment: The number of attempts is fixed.  If you do any more, the sum of the array will be greater than the sum of the target.  In your example, the sum of the start is 10, the sum of the target is 12.  If you do two operations, the sum will be 14, so it is one operation or nothing.  Can you convert this to a general statement?

Comment: @RossMillikan suppose i have one array {2,3,4,5} and another one is {2,3,6,5} the difference between sum of these arrays is 2 divisible by (n-2)=2.but we can not change it to the desired. So how to detect such situations??

Comment: I gave a necessary, but not sufficient condition.  Given that you are going to do $n$ operations, think of one operation that adds $1$ to all the elements.  Now you have $n$ chances to subtract $2$ from any element you want.  If you can get there with that, you have an answer.  If not, there isn't one.  Expressing this correctly takes a little work.  Can you do that?

Comment: @RossMillikan you are saying there will be exact n numbers that are greater by 2 than the  corresponding element in desired array. it may be we have to perform operation (decrease by 2) several time on a single element but total of these operation will be n?? am i right?

Comment: You are right.  But you can't spread the 2's.  Think about it and you will be there.

Comment: @RossMillikan i am not getting what you mean by "But you can't spread the 2's". I am not good in english. Please sir be clear about that . m not gatting!

Comment: Look at the parity of the differences between what you have before deducting the 2's and the target.  If any are odd, you are sunk.

Comment: Sir i am extreamly sorry . but i am not getting what you want to say . Sir please give an example if possible.Please!

Comment: In your example 1234 to 2145, add 1 to all of them getting 2345, then subtract 2 from the second to get 2145.  Success.  If you were trying to get to 1245, you can't get there because you need to subtract 1 from each of the fist two.  If you were trying to get to 1238 you would add 1 to everything twice to get to 3456, but you can't subtract 2 from three and add to one, so fail.

Comment: Solution will not be possible if after adding one's we get any of these conditions 1.difference between  any corresponding elements is odd 2.if there is any element that is lesser than corresponding target array element. sufficient ??

Comment: I think the easier statement is:  let there be $n$ numbers.  Find $d$, the difference of the sums.  If $n-2$ doesn't divide $d$, it is not possible.  Otherwise add $\frac d{n-2}$ to all of them.  If the new value is greater than or equal to the target and the difference is even, the conversion is possible, otherwise not.

Comment: thanx a lot Ross ... you are very nice and helpfull .. i got yhings now. :)

Comment: one more condition d>=0(target -initial) ??.

Comment: That is correct unless you also permit going backwards-subtract one from all but one and add one to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Just one:
$$
\left\{1 + 1,2 - 1,3 + 1,4 + 1\right\}
=
\left\{2,1,4,5\right\}
$$

Let's $\vec{e}_{1} \equiv \left\{1,0,0,\ldots\right\}$,
$\vec{e}_{2} \equiv \left\{0,1,0,\ldots\right\}, \ldots$. $\vec{r}_{i}$ and $\vec{r}_{f}$ are the initial and final arrays, respectively. Then, after $n$
iterations, we'll have:
$$
\vec{r}_{f}
=
n\left(\vec{r}_{i} + \sum_{\ell = 1}^{4}\vec{e}_{\ell}\right)
-
2\sum_{\left\{j\right\}}\vec{e}_{j}
$$
where $\left\{j\right\}$ is the set of $n$ indexes we choose along the iteration procedure. Since
$\displaystyle{\vec{R} = \vec{r}_{i} + \sum_{\ell = 1}^{4}\vec{e}_{\ell}}$
is known, we have the condition:
$$
\vec{r}_{f}
=
n\vec{R} - 2\sum_{\left\{j\right\}}\vec{e}_{j}
$$
It shows that the result is independent of the order we choose $j$ in the
$\left\{j\right\}$ set.

Comment: i need a general solution for any arrays????

Comment: @SagarNishad 0 k.

Answer (score 0):

Your operation can be separated into 2 commutative operations:

1. increase everything by 1
2. decrease a chosen element by 2

First, figure out how many times that operation was applied by finding q such that q*(n-2) = the difference in the sum of elements. Obviously if q is not a natural number it's impossible.

Next, increase everything in array1 by q, let's call this array1'. If the difference between each element in array1' and array2 is a negative multiple of 2, it is possible. Otherwise it's not.

Comment: suppose i have one array {2,3,4,5} and another one is {2,3,6,5} the difference between sum of these arrays is 2 divisible by (n-2)=2.but we can not change it to the desired. So how to detect such situations? You are saying to increase all by q as a result of operation one then there should be q such elements that have difference of two or it may also happen we have to apply operation to on a single element s more than once??